# JQuery select from selection

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="class1"><td>1</td><td class="Type">Type 1</td><td>Section 205</td><</tr>  
  <tr class="class2"><td>2</td><td class="Type">Type 1</td><td>Section 225</td></tr>
  <tr class="class2"><td>3</td><td class="Type">Type 2</td><td>Section 115</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to select a row which has an specific class and one of the colums contains an specific text. I know how to do the second thing with: `$("td.Type:contains(Type 1)").parent()` but that would select the first and second rows, and I only want those which class is 2 (That is, the second one).  I though I could do a selector inside a selector and I try with `$("tr.class2 td.Type:contains(Type1)").parent()` which doesn't select anything at all, and `$("tr.class2").$("td.Type:contains(Type1)").parent()` which isn't even a valid javascript command.

I was searching and I only could find how to get a sum of selections with `$(selector 1, selector 2)`, which is not what I pretend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a selector to the `parent('.class2')` function

```js
$('#result').append($("td.Type:contains(Type 1)").parent('.class2').attr('class'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="class1"><td>1</td><td class="Type">Type 1</td><td>Section 205</td></tr>  
  <tr class="class2"><td>2</td><td class="Type">Type 1</td><td>Section 225</td></tr>
  <tr class="class2"><td>3</td><td class="Type">Type 2</td><td>Section 115</td></tr>
</table><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="result">Result: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("td.Type:contains(Type1)").parent('tr.class2');
```